# What is moving horizon estimation/receding horizon estimation? In simple words?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

> What is moving horizon estimation/receding horizon estimation? In simple words?

I am not a professional but I really have to figure this out.
I have done some research online, but cannot understand those mathematical formulas. So please explain it simply, just like teaching a child.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on it is terrible. What do you need to learn it for? If it's just to get an overview, maybe that can be done without formulas,  but usually if you need to learn something and it involves formulas you need to learn the formulas. My child is $1$ year old now but she will be learning formulas as early as she can, and that is way before she gets to school. This toxic environment of anti-math in the US needs to be dispelled. (Sorry for the rant.)

Comment: I just need to have a general understanding of it. No need of mathematical formulas. Do you have some simple examples than can help me to have a scratch on it?

Comment: no, that's why I looked at the Wikipedia article, to see if I could get enough of an idea to explain it. I couldn't. I'm not at all familiar with it.

Comment: it's very kind of you. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words, 
**When is it used?** to estimate system states, extract state information especially from a noisy measurement.
**Why called moving horizon?** The measurement slot changes..or  at each sample,  a fixed window of past measurements is used to estimate the current state of the system. Usually the estimation of state is used along with the model to forecast the future process behavior for a fixed time-window.

**Estimation and control** With the help of available data in each window (measurement slot) dynamic optimization computes
the optimal sequence of manipulable variables (inputs to the process) such that the predicted process behavior is as desirable as possible subject to the physical and operational constraints of the system. This is when control comes into picture with the estimated state information.

Comment: thank you very much. really helps a lot